# Making the height of my css boxes liquified

Tags: css, html

I need your help,

How can the existing code below be modified such that the height of my css boxes are then liquified (as it needs to be this way to adjust to the height of my users screen resolution)?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

<style type="text/css">
* { margin:0; padding: 0 }
#container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#primary {
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    background: red;
    height: 600px;
}

#content {
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
    background: blue;
    height: 600px;
}

#secondary {
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    background: green;
    height: 600px;
}


</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="container">


    <div id="primary">
        <p>left</p>
    </div>


    <div id="content">
        <p>center</p>
    </div>


    <div id="secondary">
        <p>right</p>
    </div>


</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just remove the fixed heights?

Comment: Could you at least indent and format the html/css nicely? It is hard to determine which elements are nested within one another.

Comment: Your ultimate goal is equal height columns or something else?

Comment: thats correct cimmamon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equal height columns can easily be achieved by using the table* display properties.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/2iy6anjy

```
#container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#primary {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 10%;
    background: red;
}

#content {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 80%;
    background: blue;
}

#secondary {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 10%;
    background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the jQuery Equal Heights plugin by Filament:

https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-Equal-Heights

Initialise it:

```
$('#container div').equalHeights();
```

Answer (score 0):

remove fixed height and give `overflow:hidden`